# Nervous For Meeting With Client

Tags: meetings

Wednesday my bosses and I have a meeting with a big client.

Its stressing me out so much because i am so worried that the client will point out everything I did wrong or didn't do. I dont usually make too many mistakes, but I do on occasion.

This particular client I have been doing my absolute best to keep up with and doing what needs to be done. Due to the nature of my job I have other responsibilities where I cant always be on top of my game with them.

And I am worried this will negatively effect my standing with my bosses as last week the boss I reported to told me I will be receiving a salary adjustment as he sees potential in what I can do and the amount of work I have been taking on.

That sounds like a raise to me. Truth be told i dont want to deal with this client anymore.

Can you please give me some advice as to how to handle this situation?

Comment: Do you have a particular question that we can help you with ?

Comment: Is there any *specific* reason why you think they would "point out everything I did wrong"?

Comment: This is a statement of how you feel, not a question. Calm down, do your best, listen to feedback and respond intelligently to it, don't be afraid to say "hey, good point, I missed that and I'll see what I can do to improve it." Nothing is ever perfect the first time out. And sometimes the customer is wrong too.

Comment: So what if the client points out issues? It is normal to have issues. Make sure that you have a process to write down all the issues so that they can be handled in a professional way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be over thinking this, it's good to be prepared for the meeting but try not to stress, if they think you are doing a bad job it's unlikely it would be raised in a meeting like this.

I suggest you have a pre-meeting with your boss and try and agree some responses if you are challenged over certain things (e.g. he may not want you to talk about other responsibilities in front of this Client).

Finally you might want to do some reading about [imposter syndrome](https://www.verywellmind.com/imposter-syndrome-and-social-anxiety-disorder-4156469).

Good luck!